# How could I prepend a field in a php form

Tags: php, mysql

I'm looking for a sql statement where I can add additoinal text to a form field when being submitted to a mysql database. For example: A field contains a file name that has been loaded to a Web server called "mydoc.pdf". I want to prepend the following text "http://www.example.com/uploads/", so when the form is submitted the field data becomes "http://www.example.com/uploads/mydoc.pdf".

Right now the unappended field "tofiles_link" uses the following mysql query statement to insert to the mysql database:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO site_tofiles (tofiles_title, tofiles_body, 
tofiles_link, tofiles_relation, tofiles_type,  tofiles_post_ip, 
tofiles_post_user) VALUES 
('".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['tofiles_title'])."', 
'".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['tofiles_body'])."', 
'".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['tofiles_link'])."', 
'".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['tofiles_relation'])."', 
'".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['tofiles_type'])."',  
'".mysql_real_escape_string($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])."', 
'".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['tofiles_post_user'])."')");

echo "Data was Entered Successfully!\n";
mysql_close($conn);
```

Can this be modified to suit my puroses? THX

Comment: This is so easy I have to assume you've made no effort to solve this yourself

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm an amateur at best when it comes to sql statements, and not everyone has all the answers like you... unless you are willing to share?

Comment: You do realize that you can do this in PHP, too, right?

Comment: I'm just looking for a solution here.

Comment: HINT `'youcanputyourtexthere".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['tofiles_link'])."', `

Comment: Doesn't work. When data is passed to the confirmation page it breaks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To make the code more readable I would do your escaping before creating the SQL query. Not required but makes the code easier to read.

```
$title = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['tofiles_title']);
$body = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['tofiles_body']);
$link = "http://www.example.com/uploads/" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['tofiles_link']);
$relation = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['tofiles_relation']);
$type = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['tofiles_type']);
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$post_user = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['tofiles_post_user']);
```

Notice the $link variable on the 3rd line above adds the URL to the string.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO site_tofiles (tofiles_title, tofiles_body, tofiles_link, tofiles_relation, tofiles_type,  tofiles_post_ip, tofiles_post_user) VALUES ";
$sql .= "('$title', '$body', '$link', '$relation', '$type', '$ip', '$post_user');";
mysql_query($sql);

echo "Data was Entered Successfully!\n";
mysql_close($conn);
```

Comment: he should be using `mysqli` prepared statements or `pdo` this code is not secure

Comment: Works great. Thanks for the quick response and taking the time to answer my question in a straight forward way... unlike some other people on this form.

Comment: cmorriessey, I agree there is a more secure way of doing this. I posted the code to closely match what he was using. If you want to convert this code to mysqli with prepared statements here is a good page to reference: [http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'm actually modifying/enhancing a legacy PHP website that is several years old and a lot of "old" code. Fortunately, its a secured login to access the site, so hopefully this lessens the security issues somewhat. Thanks again.